# How to access parent value from nested TableColumn

Tags: javafx, tableview, fxml, tablecolumn

I have a table (`TableView`) in which there is frequent repetition of a group of columns (for example, name and address). I group these columns as sub-columns of a common column

```
<TableColumn text="Получател">
    <columns>
        <TableColumn text="ЕИК"/>
        <TableColumn text="ЗДДС №"/>
        <TableColumn text="Име"/>
        <TableColumn text="Адрес"/>
        <TableColumn text="Материално отговорно лице"/>
        <TableColumn text="Получател"/>
    </columns>
</TableColumn>
```

I export this group of columns to user control

```
<fx:root type="com.example.CompanyTableColumn" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
         text="${controller.name}">

    <columns>
        <TableColumn fx:id="eikColumn" text="ЕИК"/>
        <TableColumn fx:id="vatColumn" text="ЗДДС №"/>
        <TableColumn fx:id="nameColumn" text="Име"/>
        <TableColumn fx:id="addressColumn" text="Адрес"/>
        <TableColumn text="Материално отговорно лице"/>
    </columns>

</fx:root>
```

```
public class CompanyTableColumn extends TableColumn<Invoice, Company> {

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Invoice, String> eikColumn;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Invoice, String> vatColumn;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Invoice, String> nameColumn;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Invoice, String> addressColumn;

    private StringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty();

    public CompanyTableColumn() {
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/com/example/table_column_company.fxml"));
            loader.setRoot(this);
            loader.setController(this);

            loader.load();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @FXML
    private void initialize() {
        
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name.get();
    }

    public StringProperty nameProperty() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name.set(name);
    }
}
```

By initializing user control as follows

```
<TableView fx:id="tableView">
    <columns>
        <CompanyTableColumn fx:id="supplierColumn" name="Доставчик"/>
        <CompanyTableColumn fx:id="receiverColumn" name="Получател"/>
    <columns>
</TableView>
```

```
supplierColumn.setCellValueFactory(cdf -> new SimpleObjectProperty<>(cdf.getValue().getSupplier()));
receiverColumn.setCellValueFactory(cdf -> new SimpleObjectProperty<>(cdf.getValue().getReceiver()));
```

And here comes my problem. In the example, the two controls must visualize data from different instances of the `Company` model. I submit the various instances by creating a CellValueFactory but I don't see how I can access the specific value in `CompanyTableColumn` so I can use it in the factories that create the values of the nested columns.

edit

As usual, the solution is found shortly after the question is asked:

```
@FXML
private void initialize() {
    eikColumn.setCellValueFactory(cdf -> new SimpleStringProperty(getCellObservableValue(cdf.getValue()).getValue().getEik()));
    vatColumn.setCellValueFactory(cdf -> new SimpleStringProperty(getCellObservableValue(cdf.getValue()).getValue().getVat()));
    nameColumn.setCellValueFactory(cdf -> new SimpleStringProperty(getCellObservableValue(cdf.getValue()).getValue().getName()));
    addressColumn.setCellValueFactory(cdf -> new SimpleStringProperty(getCellObservableValue(cdf.getValue()).getValue().getAddress()));
}
```

Comment: If you've found a solution please consider putting it in an actual answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution I found consisted of calling [`TableColumn::getCellObservableValue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableColumn.html#getCellObservableValue-S-) using the value corresponding to the corresponding row in the table as a parameter (returned by the `CellDataFeatures` object used in the callback function to generate a value)

```
public class CompanyTableColumn extends TableColumn<Invoice, Company> {

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Invoice, String> eikColumn;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Invoice, String> vatColumn;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Invoice, String> nameColumn;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Invoice, String> addressColumn;

    private StringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty();

    public CompanyTableColumn() {
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/com/example/table_column_company.fxml"));
            loader.setRoot(this);
            loader.setController(this);

            loader.load();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @FXML
    private void initialize() {
        eikColumn.setCellValueFactory(cdf -> new SimpleStringProperty(getCellObservableValue(cdf.getValue()).getValue().getEik()));
        vatColumn.setCellValueFactory(cdf -> new SimpleStringProperty(getCellObservableValue(cdf.getValue()).getValue().getVat()));
        nameColumn.setCellValueFactory(cdf -> new SimpleStringProperty(getCellObservableValue(cdf.getValue()).getValue().getName()));
        addressColumn.setCellValueFactory(cdf -> new SimpleStringProperty(getCellObservableValue(cdf.getValue()).getValue().getAddress()));
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name.get();
    }

    public StringProperty nameProperty() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name.set(name);
    }
}
```